# Random Access to Pointer Vector

Tags: c++, vector, containers

I implemented a graph data structure using list.

```
list<int> *adjList;
```

This is the output of this list.

```
0-->1,2,
1-->0,3,
2-->0,4,
3-->1,
4-->2,5,
5-->4,
```

I am trying to reverse this graph. I created vector for this purpose.

**What I tried**

```
vector<int> *transpose;
```

**With the following function, I am adding the elements of this list to transpose.**

```
  void transposeGraph(){
        for(int i=0; i<V; i++){
                for(int node:adjList[i]){
                    cout<<node << " ";
                    transpose[node].push_back(i);
            }
                cout<<endl;
        }
    }
```

However, when I print the transpose, I am having the same result as a list. It is not reversing it. Where am I making a mistake?

**Question 2**

I read that random access is possible in vectors but not in the list.

Why the following print statement gives me the error? Is it because I have a pointer in the definition?

```
 for(int i=0; i<V; i++){
          cout<<transpose[i]<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: `list<int> *adjList;` -- Why not `std::vector<std::list<int>> adjList;`?  Then you won't have pointers to deal with.  Second, what exactly do you mean by "reversing the graph"?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: If it is a directed graph, I interpreted it as reversing the directions of all the edges.

Comment: Your adjacency matrix is symmetric - for every `a-->b` there's also a `b-->a`. So of course the inverse of it is equal to the original.

Comment: Is there a reason for *pointers to std::list* versus a `std::list`, like `std::list<int> adj_list;`?  *(Note: C++ is not C# nor Java and does not require variables allocated from dynamic memory.)*

Comment: @ThomasMatthews From the usage, it's clear that `adj_list` points to an array of lists, not a single list. Observe `adjList[i]`